# Sequence contains more than one element error when using bind with multiple constructor parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ninject.web.mvc

Using `MVC5` with `ninject` 3.2 version I noticed `ninject` is throwing this error

```
Sequence contains more than one element
```

when resolving/injecting dependency

I have an email service that uses `sendgrid` to send emails from an `MVC 5` application running in `Azure WebSites`

if I register the service like following in ninjectwebcommon, it works

```
var sgUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SG_UserName"];
var sgPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SG_Password"];

//Register email service
kernel.Bind<IEmailService>()
    .To<EmailService>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("userName", sgUserName)
    .WithConstructorArgument("password", sgPassword);
```

Below code gives the

```
Sequence contains more than one element
```

error when resolving/injecting dependency. Not sure if this is a known issue or not

```
var sgUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SG_UserName"];
var sgPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SG_Password"];

//Register email service
kernel.Bind<IEmailService>()
    .To<EmailService>()
    .WithConstructorArgument(sgUserName)
    .WithConstructorArgument(sgPassword);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but want to answer for anyone that happens upon this error.
It might be OK to leave out the ArgumentName when there is only one.
I wouldn't and haven't.
ArgumentName is required for each when there is more than one argument.
It is not really an issue, .WithConstructorsArgument simply requires and argument name.